# Viewing Word Docs READ ONLY

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report reading records out of a DMS system and I thought it would be nice to have a link to the documents that it is listing so that the users could view the actual documents.

However when it displays a Word doc it allows you to make changes and then save them, which rather undermines the DMS system.

I don't think there is a parameter (/r) in Word that does this so do any of you clever people out there have a solution please?

Comment: Which DMS? Your description of the linking behavior indicates that documents in the DMS are still accessible over the network, circumventing the DMS, somehow. Some DMS offer a linking format that integrats with the DMS application, so that files linked are opened and checked out appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP101640101033.aspx?pid=CH100487461033) to the command line switches in Word 2007.  There does not appear to be such an option as you describe.  The /r switch re-registers Word in the registry and closes.  Probably the best way to do this is [download the Word Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3657CE88-7CFA-457A-9AEC-F4F827F20CAC&DisplayLang=en) and use it to open the document rather than Word itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to write a small web component, write a component that takes an ID and streams out the document, then link to that service from the report. The web server will make a local copy of the document for reading.

Of course, then users will be frustrated that their changes are going into a black hole, but it sounds like that may be a better problem to have.

[There's a better answer for those using Sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86033/how-do-i-make-a-microsoft-word-document-read-only-within-a-sharepoint-document)